# Where can one find a reliable information about health effects of sitting with one's back to a door

Tags: mental-health, research, stress, sitting, instinct

An opinion exists that sitting with one's back towards the door isn't good for you. I've heard/read that it is connected to our primal need to know what is behind us.

The effects can vary, from lowered levels of concentration to increased stress levels and all other bad things that follow that.

However, in my short search I failed to find any reliable sources for this topic. Does anybody know of any research available about this?

Comment: Don't get the question. What's the problem? What kind of mental health issues are you referring to? Please elaborate

Comment: I also had no idea what you were asking and was about to vote to close until I googled it. Your question would be much clearer if you explained the claims your question refers to. Links would be a bonus.

Comment: Fair point, I updated the question.

Comment: This sounds like something said in an action movie, a thriller, or maybe _film noir_.  Are you sure that what you read wasn't a misquote from some source like that?  Maybe it was a rationalization of how such a quote could be medically substantiated?  Maybe it was a joke, as such?